# Xamarin: Unable to run iOS App from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am unable to run iOS App from VS 2015 on Windows.  I can see the Mac agent is connected to my Mac but there is following error in the log file.  Can someone please advise what is going wrong here?

> Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingFileManager Error: 0 :
>   [2016-12-16 17:53:15.3687] An error occurred downloading files for App
>   App3 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file
>   '/var/empty/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App3/c401707f0c87e530ed45cad421856e4f/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/build-signature/signature'
>   was not found on the Mac.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution before re-building?

Comment: Yes.  I did try Clean and Build.

Comment: You could try deleting your entire cache in the App3 folder on the Mac, and manually remove all 'bin' and 'obj' folders from your project on the PC, then clean and rebuild.

Comment: @AlanClark It didn't work but gave me some idea that helped me to proceed.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build the application but it was not launching iOS simulator and the log was pointing to error mentioned above.  After @AlanClark's comment, I started examining the contents of folders on my mac.  There are two places where the contents of the app are copied on Mac.

1. /var/empty/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App3/c401707f0c87e530ed45cad421856e4f/
2. /Users//Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App3/c401707f0c87e530ed45cad421856e4f/

I noticed that there was **obj** folder in location 2 but it was not there in location 1.  I manually copied the obj folder and I could launch the app after that.  Still trying to figure out why obj folder is missing from location 2.